# security patch list for Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

Tags: updates, security

I want to get the list of all the security patches available for my system on the official Ubuntu repo without updating. I need this to forward the list to the application owners and once they confirm the compatibility, i need to install them manually.

Can any one advice on how to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe `sudo apt update ; apt list --upgradeable`? That would list all updates though, not only security. I'm not sure if you can determine the origin repository from the output, can't test here currently.

Comment: https://usn.ubuntu.com/usn/trusty/

Answer (score 3):

You won't get a list of "patches" directly, but security updates are accompanied by [Ubuntu Security Notices](https://usn.ubuntu.com/usn/). Each notice includes the packages affected, a description of the vulnerability, the versions with the fix and any additional steps needed. You can then obtain the diff from the Launchpad page of the package, which is linked to in the USN.

For example, from [USN-3401-1](https://usn.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-3401-1/):

> [image]

The version number ([`2015.20160320-1ubuntu0.1`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/texlive-base/2015.20160320-1ubuntu0.1)) is a link to the Launchpad page of that version of the package, where you'll see:

> [image]

which is a link to [the diff](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/334090229/texlive-base_2015.20160320-1_2015.20160320-1ubuntu0.1.diff.gz).